# How to visualize a data drift?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, visualization, data-stream-mining, concept-drift

I want to show that my data distribution changes between data windows. Is it enough to visualize the mean and variance for every window? Is there any other solution? thank you

Comment: Why not plot the distributions?

Comment: I tried with histograms but i need to visualze the different windows . Also my data is high dimensional i have more than 10 features